# D3.js line chart with dates on x axes

Tags: javascript, d3.js, charts, linechart

I'm working on this line chart with d3.js . 
I have a problem formatting the dates and as much I change the parseDate field, there is no way I can find to get for example "15 June". 
If I change .tickformat in the x axis on %d I will just have "01 Oct" and not the exact date.

Here is the JS fiddle 
http://jsfiddle.net/w0d4t1n5/

```
<script async src="//jsfiddle.net/w0d4t1n5/embed/"></script>
```

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand, you want every datapoint's date displayed on the x axis, instead of just a time division.

For that, you need to create an ordinal scale and call that in the X axis:

fiddle is here:

http://jsfiddle.net/z94uzc0L/1/

```
  var margin = {
    top: 30,
    right: 100,
    bottom: 30,
    left: 50
  },
  width = 365 - margin.left - margin.right,
  height = 280 - margin.top - margin.bottom,
  padding = 1;

var parseDate = d3.time.format("%d-%b-%y").parse;

// Set the ranges
var x = d3.time.scale()
  .range([10, width - 15]);

//ordinal scale
var x2 = d3.scale.ordinal().rangePoints([0, width ], .25)

var y = d3.scale.linear()
  .range([height, 0]);

var xAxis = d3.svg.axis().scale(x2)
  .orient("bottom")
  .tickFormat(d3.time.format("%b %d"))
  .ticks(4)
  .tickPadding(2);

var yAxis = d3.svg.axis().scale(y)
  .orient("left");

var valueline = d3.svg.line()
  .interpolate("basis")
  .x(function(d) {
    return x(d.date);
  })
  .y(function(d) {
    return y(d.trump);
  });

var valueline2 = d3.svg.line()
  .interpolate("basis")
  .x(function(d) {
    return x(d.date);
  })
  .y(function(d) {
    return y(d.clinton);
  });

//florida

var chart1 = d3.select("#florida")
  .append("svg")
  .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
  .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
  .append("g")
  .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

//needed for the grid
function make_y_axis() {
  return d3.svg.axis()
    .scale(y)
    .orient("left")
}

data1 = [{
  "date": "15-Jun-16",
  "trump": 43.4,
  "clinton": 44
}, {
  "date": "15-Jul-16",
  "trump": 43.4,
  "clinton": 44
}, {
  "date": "15-Aug-16",
  "trump": 42,
  "clinton": 45.6
}, {
  "date": "15-Sep-16",
  "trump": 45.1,
  "clinton": 44.4
}, {
  "date": "06-Oct-16",
  "trump": 43.3,
  "clinton": 46.2
}, {
  "date": "10-Oct-16",
  "trump": 49.3,
  "clinton": 49.2
}];



var color = d3.scale.ordinal().range(["#004ecc", "#cc0000"]);
//d3.csv("data.csv", function(error, data) {
data1.forEach(function(d) {
  d.date = parseDate(d.date);
  d.trump = +d.trump;
  d.clinton = +d.clinton;
});

// Scale the range of the data


x.domain(d3.extent(data1, function(d) {
  return d.date;
}));
y.domain([36, 50]);

//update ordinal scale domain
x2.domain(data1.map(function(d) { return d.date; }));

//add the grid
chart1.append("g")
  .attr("class", "grid")
  .call(make_y_axis()
    .tickSize(-width, 0, 0)
    .tickFormat("")
  )

chart1.append("path")
  .attr("class", "line")
  .attr("stroke", "red")
  .attr("d", valueline(data1));

chart1.append("path")
  .attr("class", "line2")
  .attr("d", valueline2(data1));

// Add the X Axis
chart1.append("g")
  .attr("class", "x axis")
  .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
  .call(xAxis);

// Add the Y Axis
chart1.append("g")
  .attr("class", "y axis")
  .call(yAxis);

chart1.append("text")
  .attr("transform", "translate(" + (width + 3) + "," + y(data1[0].clinton) + ")")
  .attr("x", ".1em")
  .attr("y", "-40")
  .attr("text-anchor", "start")
  .style("fill", "red")
  .style("font-size", "15")
  .style("font-weight", "bold")
  .text("Clinton 46.2%");

chart1.append("text")
  .attr("transform", "translate(" + (width + 3) + "," + y(data1[0].trump) + ")")
  .attr("x", ".1em")
  .attr("y", "10")
  .attr("text-anchor", "start")
  .style("fill", "steelblue")
  .style("font-size", "15")
  .style("font-weight", "bold")
  .text("Trump 43.3%");

//plus 1: animation

var curtain = chart1.append('rect')
  .attr('x', -1 * width)
  .attr('y', -1 * height)
  .attr('height', height)
  .attr('width', width)
  .attr('class', 'curtain')
  .attr('transform', 'rotate(180)')
  .style('fill', '#ffffff')

/* Optionally add a guideline */
var guideline = chart1.append('line')
  .attr('stroke', '#333')
  .attr('stroke-width', 0.4)
  .attr('class', 'guide')
  .attr('x1', 1)
  .attr('y1', 1)
  .attr('x2', 1)
  .attr('y2', height)

var t = chart1.transition()
  .delay(120)
  .duration(500)
  .ease('linear')
  .each('end', function() {
    d3.select('line.guide')
      .transition()
      .style('opacity', 0)
      .remove()
  });

t.select('rect.curtain')
  .attr('width', 0);
t.select('line.guide')
  .attr('transform', 'translate(' + width + ', 0)')

d3.select("#show_guideline").on("change", function(e) {
  guideline.attr('stroke-width', this.checked ? 1 : 0);
  curtain.attr("opacity", this.checked ? 0.75 : 1);
});
```

Comment: Hi Oraz! Thank you very much. I was trying to work it out exactly in the same way when I read first your answer. I was missing this line of code `x2.domain(data1.map(function(d) { return d.date; }));`. Thank you very much for your help!